# Is this an Ideal Memory Startup for Python Spyder?

Tags: python, profiling, memory-profiling

Here is the RAM Usage when I run Spyder Active:

[image]

I wonder if this RAM usage is normal (with having no objects defined in Python)? Here is all builtin Objects contained so far

[image]

[image]

So I run this custom Memory Profiler to check in directly:

```
def memory_inspector():
    import pandas as pd
    import sys
    print(sys.getsizeof({}))
    print(sys.getsizeof([]))
    print(sys.getsizeof(set()))

    from guppy import hpy
    h = hpy()
    print(h.heap())

    import gc
    for x in range(0,5):
        print(gc.collect())

    from pympler import muppy, summary
    all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
    sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
    # Prints out a summary of the large objects
    summary.print_(sum1)
    # Get references to certain types of objects such as dataframe
    dataframes = [ao for ao in all_objects if isinstance(ao, pd.DataFrame)]
    for d in dataframes:
      print(d.columns.values)
      print(len(d))
```

And here is the Output I get:

```
 memory_inspector()

240
64
224
Partition of a set of 584859 objects. Total size = 70874332 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 155292  27 20362407  29  20362407  29 str
     1 148846  25 11896144  17  32258551  46 tuple
     2  65790  11  5071067   7  37329618  53 bytes
     3  33434   6  4837624   7  42167242  59 types.CodeType
     4  30565   5  4156840   6  46324082  65 function
     5   3787   1  3650848   5  49974930  71 type
     6   7652   1  3216168   5  53191098  75 dict (no owner)
     7   3787   1  2065200   3  55256298  78 dict of type
     8   1359   0  2029176   3  57285474  81 dict of module
     9    665   0  1087328   2  58372802  82 dict of sip.wrappertype
<1752 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
12
2
2
2
2
                                types |   # objects |   total size
===================================== | =========== | ============
                          <class 'str |      157980 |     19.65 MB
  <class 'guppy.sets.setsc.ImmNodeSet |        1795 |      9.03 MB
                         <class 'dict |       15982 |      8.03 MB
                        <class 'bytes |       65800 |      4.84 MB
                         <class 'code |       33744 |      4.66 MB
                         <class 'type |        3301 |      3.33 MB
                          <class 'int |       39687 |      1.07 MB
                        <class 'tuple |       15529 |      1.00 MB
                          <class 'set |         922 |    844.44 KB
                         <class 'list |        6113 |    832.86 KB
         <class 'sip.methoddescriptor |       15059 |    823.54 KB
              <class 'sip.wrappertype |         663 |    683.72 KB
                      <class 'weakref |        7907 |    617.73 KB
                 <class 'sip.enumtype |         555 |    572.34 KB
           <class 'wrapper_descriptor |        6491 |    507.11 KB
```

Can anyone Interpret this results in detail of what is going on? is it possible to minimize the memory usage at this point, even if there are no objects defined in Python?

Comment: 70 megabytes? Sounds normal... you've imported `pandas` after all. But that looks like  a normal python runtime takes that about 4.5 megabytes, usually. But it depends. Is that really a problem for you? 4.5 megabytes isn't a lot at all, are you working in an embedded environment?

Comment: I see so thats Normal.. no I thought that it may be a little Expensive in RAM total that exceeds 400MB and maybe related with the Memory Profiler above , Since my RAM  limited to 2GB, I may try to discuss it if it normal or not

Comment: Yes, I mean, IDEs are notorious for being bloated memory hogs. You could try to use something like VS Code. Even that is going to push your 2 gigabytes of RAM. There's always VIM and Emacs... those are excellent text editors, once you learn to use them effectively.